Morley Rank of disjunction is equal to the maximum of the Morley Rank of the disjuncts
I want to prove that if $X_1, X_2$ are definable subsets (in some suitable theory), then the Morley rank $$\text{MR}(X_1 \cup X_2) = \max(\text{MR(}X_1), \text{MR}(X_2))$$ where MR(-) denotes the Morley rank. This is in Marker's Model Theory (Lemma 6.2.7 ii).
I'm trying to prove this by induction and it seems clear to me that this is true if the $\text{MR}(X_1 \cup X_2)$ is a limit ordinal, however I don't see why it would be true in the successor ordinal case.
It seems like I can also prove this by using the fact that the Morley rank of a definable subset X is equal to the supremum of the Morley ranks of the types generated by elements of X. Again, it seems clear that $$\text{MR}(X) \geq \sup\{\text{MR}(tp(\overline{a})): \overline{a} \in X\}.$$ However I'm unsure how to prove the other direction, especially in the case that $\sup\{\text{MR}(tp(\overline{a})): \overline{a} \in X\}$ is a limit ordinal (otherwise I think you could use the fact that X must have finitely many types of maximal rank).
Not only am I not sure how to prove this, but this comes after the lemma I am trying to prove in the first place as well (Lemma 6.2.16 in Marker).
Marker seems to indicate both of these problems should be easy, but I am having some trouble figuring out what to do here, so help with either of this directions would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: Here's the definition of Morley Rank I'm using. 

Maybe you could include the definition of Morley rank in the question. There are several equivalent ways to define it, and readers may not remember which definition Marker uses.

One direction immediately follows from the previous exercise that $\operatorname{MR}(X)\le \operatorname{MR}(Y)$ for $X\subseteq Y,$ which is a straightforward consequence of the definition.
For the other direction, if $\operatorname{MR}(X\cup Y)\ge \alpha+1$ then let $Z_i\subseteq X\cup Y$ be disjoint with $\operatorname{MR}(Z_i)\ge \alpha.$ Observe that $Z_i = (X\cap Z_i)\cup(Y\cap Z_i)$ and so by induction, we can assume that for all $i$, we have $\max(\operatorname{MR}(X\cap Z_i), \operatorname{MR}(Y\cap Z_i))\ge \alpha.$ Then either infinitely many $i$ have $\operatorname{MR}(X\cap Z_i)\ge \alpha$ or infinitely many have $\operatorname{MR}(Y\cap Z_i)\ge \alpha.$

Oh that makes sense. Thanks for the help
